# Ruby on rails :- Could not find RubyGem rails (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am very new to Ruby on Rails. I installed ruby on rails on my Windows 7 using the installer in http://railsinstaller.org/. I could create a project once and thereafter I was not (I dont know what did I do in between :-( ).

The complete errors messages are :-

**On creating a new project** :-

```
c:\Sites>rails new Tickets_Test
E:/Ashish/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:762:in `report_activate_error': Cou
ld not find RubyGem rails (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
        from E:/Ashish/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:219:in `activate'
        from E:/Ashish/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1065:in `gem'
        from E:/Ashish/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/bin/rails:18:in `<main>'
```

**on just getting the version**:-

```
c:\Sites>rails --version
E:/Ashish/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:762:in `report_activate_error': Cou
ld not find RubyGem rails (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
        from E:/Ashish/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:219:in `activate'
        from E:/Ashish/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1065:in `gem'
        from E:/Ashish/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/bin/rails:18:in `<main>'
```

Any idea why the above is happening?

**EDIT**

Appearently there are two command prompts :-
 Ruby command prompt :-
[image: Ruby]
and
 Ruby for rails command prompt (The problem is resolved using this command prompt):-
[image: Ruby on rails]

I was using ruby command prompt. Sounds like a stupid question, however, I am not sure how there are "two" command prompts?

Comment: this might not be very helpful, but ruby / rails on windows is a big PITA. Try installing cygwing and using the version that comes with it, you might experience a bit less frustrations. The best solution (at least for me) is to run ruby on linux. If you don't want to install linux on your PC, try using a VM such as VirtualPC or VirtualBOX. Sorry that I'm not of **real** help, but I've stopped trying to run ruby on windows.

Comment: @Augusto, I updated my question. I am sure people in the community are working hard to make ruby friends to windows. Check out rubyinstaller.org :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to have two Ruby versions in your system, 1.9.1 and 1.8.7. Rails gem seems to be installed only for one of them. I'd suggest you to remove one of these versions, and reinstall Rails.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into a similar issues after installing heroku toolbelt. I found that heroku added the second one to my path. I removed it from the path and life seems good again!

Answer (score 2):

If you have two Ruby versions in your system, 1.9.1 and 1.8.7, then no need to remove any. You can switch between these two Ruby versions with the help of RVM on OS X and Linux. And for Windows you can use Pik.

For further details, you can go through posts - http://rorguide.blogspot.com/2011/03/pik-rvm-tools-to-manage-multiple-ruby.html

Answer (score 1):

Try using Pik (available at http://github.com) to switch between the two or edit your path to include one but not the other. That's simpler.